# Proposed Tag: Probabilistic Graphical model

Tags: feature-request, tags

I Searched for the PGM tag to subscribe to but could not find it.

IMHO, Probabilistic Graphical model is an essential branch of AI

Thanks

Comment: Please make a more elaborate case for this tag.  (I'd have no problem adding it, especially if we get a question that involves PGM, but it's not a subject I have any background in, so I can't make the determination as to the utility of such as tag with so little information.)

Comment: @DukeZhou After this my meta post, https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1538/2444, you can see that we have a tag [tag:probabilistic], which, IMHO, should be deleted. A probabilistic graphical model is a quite important concept in AI. A PGM can be directed (Bayesian network) or undirected (MRFs). PGM are also associated with the concept of causation, which is a really important concept in AI.

Comment: @nbro let me know you thoughts on replacing the "probabilistic" tag.  (Skimming the  21 instances now.)  Also, am I reading your comment correctly in thinking we should also create a "probablistic graphical model" tag?

Comment: @DukeZhou I would need some time to review all the questions that are currently tagged as "probabilistic", but the tag probabilistic, IMHO, makes little sense anyway, so I think it should be deleted or replaced, but, as I said, I need to review all those questions first to give you my opinion regarding the idea of replacing it with PGM.

Comment: [Questions like this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/5177/please-explain-this-log-probability-function-what-does-each-part-mean) don't seem to be PGN, but do make me wonder if there is some need for a general probability tag...

Comment: @DukeZhou I think that this why we have the tag [tag:math]. I think that the tag [tag:probability] (but _not_ probabilistic) would also be ok on this website, given that [tag:probability] is a widely known topic and it is highly related to AI.

Comment: @nbro strongly agree.  Quick fix may be to replace probabilistic with probability, then look for opportunities to utilize the PGN tag in specific cases.  (I'll look to do that shortly for probabilistic, in addition to merging the remaining "natural language" into the "natural language processing".