# What are the main problems of our Stack? What could we be doing better to grow?

Tags: discussion

Essentially, what are your thoughts on what we need to be doing, doing better, or not doing, to grow the Stack?

(This topic may have been covered in the past, but I wanted to open a new thread to reflect the present status.)

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems. Some of them have already been raised but not addressed.

1. Too broad questions (or posts with multiple questions) are not closed (immediately). See [Why aren't too broad questions closed?](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1536/2444).
2. Too many duplicate questions, which are not marked as duplicate. See [What should we do regarding extremely similar questions or duplicates?](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1532/2444).
3. The on-topic and off-topic pages of the site are not clear enough. See [On-topic and off-topic pages need to be clarified](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1506/2444).
4. In general, new users should have a clear idea of the most appropriate website to ask a question (among AI SE, Data Science SE, Stats SE, and Stack Overflow), but this has not yet been clarified.
5. It is still unclear which implementation-related questions are on-topic.
6. Too many tags that should not exist because they are not directly or strictly related to our scope. See [On the management of tags on this website](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1538/2444). In general, if a question mentions e.g. a certain concept or tool, it does not mean that an associated tag needs to be created. For example, it makes sense to have a tag associated with ant-colony optimization (given that this is a theoretical AI topic), but it makes no sense to have a tag like [accessibility](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accessibility) (which is extremely vague and general). In general, only tags that are associated with common concepts should exist. We shouldn't create a tag for every possible concept or tool.
7. Some users that (constantly) provide out-of-context and poor answers. These answers often look like spam, so they degrade the quality of the website.
8. Currently and generally, moderators are often not very active, responsive and strict enough.
9. There's a need for more competent people in certain areas. It seems that the usual suspects tend to answer to almost all questions. We need more diversity and competence.

Comment: I might disagree that "accessibility" is necessarily off-topic, in that it is a concern of computing in the sense of interfaces, and that AI may be used to facilitate this.  (For instance, speech-to-text and visa versa now not requiring the cloud on mobile devices, per machine learning.)  I'd also argue that tags for specific tools are useful in searching for previous Q&A about those tools.

Comment: @DukeZhou There's just one question tagged with [tag:accessibility]. In the meta-post I had created [On the management of tags on this website](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1538/2444), I argue that only tags associated with a common AI topic (for instance, topics that have an associated Wiki article) should be created, otherwise, in principle, we could create tags for everything, but, at this point, what would be the point of having tags? I think that tags should be used to group certain questions under certain well-known sub-fields or topics of the field (in this case, AI).

Comment: The concept of accessibility may be related to AI, but only remotely. I think that all questions you could tag with accessibility may be tagged with [tag:applications].