# List of problematic tags that can lead to off-topic questions

Tags: discussion, tags, close-reasons, off-topic, closed-questions

This meta-post is meant to list tags that can lead to **off-topic** and **opinion-based questions**, in particular, programming questions, hardware-related questions, datasets and pre-trained models, and questions that can lead to opinions.

The reason why I am collecting this list is to keep an eye on these tags, and, every once in a while, check if there are off-topic questions tagged with them, and close and/or delete them. This post/list will be updated every once in a while (feel free to edit this post to include more problematic tags). So, many of these tags should not have many questions tagged with them and some of them maybe will be deleted to avoid people thinking that certain questions are on-topic here. Needless to say, you can help me to do this task and you should probably avoid using some of these tags.

This post can be thought of as a successor of [this](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1538/2444).

#### Software libraries

- [tensorflow](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow)
- [keras](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keras)
- [pytorch](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pytorch)
- [numpy](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numpy)
- [sklearn](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sklearn)
- [gym](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gym)
- [opencv](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opencv)
- [spacy](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spacy)
- [watson](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watson)
- [google-translate](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-translate)
- [deep-blue](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-blue)
- [tensorflow-probability](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow-probability)
- [tensorforce](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tensorforce)
- [google-cloud](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud)
- [kaggle](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kaggle)
- [caffe](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caffe)
- [darknet](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/darknet)
- [nltk](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nltk)
- [pybullet](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pybullet)
- [cortana](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cortana)
- [siri](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/siri)
- [stable-baselines](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stable-baselines)

#### Programming languages

- [python](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python)
- [c](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c)
- [c++](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)
- [java](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java)
- [javascript](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)
- [matlab](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matlab)

#### Software

- [software-architecture](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-architecture)
- [software-development](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-development)
- [software-evaluation](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-evaluation)
- [computer-programming](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-programming)
- [inductive-programming](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inductive-programming)
- [open-source](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source)
- [plotting](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plotting)

#### Hardware

- [hardware](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware)
- [hardware-evaluation](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware-evaluation)
- [gpu](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gpu)

#### Speculation

- [futurism](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/futurism)
- [mythology-of-ai](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology-of-ai)
- [neo-luddism](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neo-luddism)
- [singularity](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/singularity)
- [agi](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agi) (unfortunately, I need to include this one too here)
- [philosophy](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy) (idem)
- [superintelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/superintelligence)

#### Biology

- [biology](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biology)
- [brain](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brain)
- [neuroscience](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neuroscience)
- [human-like](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/human-like)
- [human-inspired](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/human-inspired)

#### Data Science

- [data-science](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-science)
- [pretrained-models](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pretrained-models)
- [data-mining](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-mining)
- [coco-dataset](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coco-dataset)
- [iris-dataset](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iris-dataset)
- [mnist](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mnist)

#### Companies

- [google](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google)
- [deepmind](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deepmind)

#### Other

The following ones will probably be all deleted meanwhile because they can be used ambiguously.

- [ai-basics](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ai-basics)
- [getting-started](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/getting-started)
- <s>[challenges](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/challenges)</s> (removed this tag from all posts, as it's very ambiguous and was being used inconsistently)
- [storage](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storage)
- [memory](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memory)
- [time](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time)